# trouble with adding second .h/cpp file to C++

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ looked at several other topics on how to include a second cpp file not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong... I'm mainly getting errors from the grid array and the enum, and apparently I can't use void for the minimax.h file either? the rest of the main.cpp file works fine so long as I compile it alone

minimax.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

void minimax(Grid& grid, Color color_player)
{
    int AI_Play;
    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand (time(NULL));

    /* generate secret number between 0 and grid size: */
    AI_Play = rand() % grid.size() + 0;
    play(grid, AI_Play, color_player)
}
```

minimax.h

```
#ifndef MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED
#define MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED

minimax(Grid& grid, Color color_player)

#endif // MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <minimax.h>

using namespace std;

//Connect Four Array
#define COLUMN 6
#define ROW 7

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 364;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 312;

enum Color {red, black, nothing};

typedef array<array<Color, ROW>, COLUMN> Grid;
```

Comment: what errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: I believe it should be `#include "minimax.h"` not `#include <minimax.h>`

Comment: for the enum and array in main.cpp I get not declared in this scope in later parts I also get the same error in minimax.cpp just tried "minimax.h" same errors also getting errors about the function in minimax being void aswell as the init for main.cpp

Comment: `minmax.cpp` doesn't know what a `Color` or `Grid` is. They should probably be included in `minmax.h`

Comment: how do I declare those in minimax.h?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
#include <minimax.h>
```

to

```
#include "minimax.h"
```

`<header name>` is for built-in header.

You need to include `Color` and `Grid` declaration inside  `minimax.h`  or put it somewhere in a file then include it inside `minimax.h`. Your `minimax.cpp` should also include `minimax.h`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the declaration of `Grid` and `Color` to minimax.h - otherwise they won't be seen within minimax.cpp . You also need to include minimax.h from minimax.cpp

Also, you should declare return type 'void' in your function in the .h. file.

Comment: I just did that seems to have fixed some errors but I'm not sure how to declare the 2d array in minimax.h

Comment: minimax.h

#ifndef MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED
#define MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED


enum Color {red, black, nothing};

typedef array<array<Color, 7>, 6> Grid;
void minimax(Grid& grid, Color color_player)
#endif // MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED

Comment: You also need to `#include <array>` in the .h file and move a few more includes as necessary. But - I/we can't take you through each failures, so my advice would be to close the question at this point, as your immediate issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

`minimax()` does not know what a `Grid` and `Color` are, because you did not define them before defining `minimax()`.  Your code needs to look more like this instead:

minimax.h

```
#ifndef MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED
#define MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED

#include <array>

//Connect Four Array
#define COLUMN 6
#define ROW 7

enum Color {red, black, nothing};

typedef std::array<std::array<Color, ROW>, COLUMN> Grid;

void minimax(Grid& grid, Color color_player);

#endif // MINIMAX_H_INCLUDED
```

minimax.cpp

```
#include "minimax.h"

#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

void minimax(Grid& grid, Color color_player)
{
    int AI_Play;
    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand (time(NULL));

    /* generate secret number between 0 and grid size: */
    AI_Play = rand() % grid.size() + 0;
    play(grid, AI_Play, color_player);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "minimax.h"

//Screen dimension constants
extern const int SCREEN_WIDTH;
extern const int SCREEN_HEIGHT;

// use minimax() as needed, eg...

int main()
{
    Grid grid;
    ...
    minimax(grid, black);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```